# Getting tabu to work with diagbox and more correctly

Tags: tables, tabu, makecell, diagbox

I have been fighting with my code for 5 hours now. How do I get

```
\documentclass[english]{article}

\usepackage[allowlitunits]{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{diagbox}

\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{Z}{S[
    table-format=1.3,
    %tight-spacing=true,
    round-mode=places,
    round-precision=3]}
\newcommand\mycell[1]{\multicolumn{1}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}c}{\makecell{#1}}}

\begin{table}
    \begin{tabu} to \linewidth {X *{8}{Z}}
    \toprule
    \rowfont[c]\bfseries
    \fbox{\diagbox{method}{missing}}
                & \mycell{ 5\%\\(mean)} & \mycell{ 5\%\\(var)}
                & \mycell{10\%\\(mean)} & \mycell{10\%\\(var)}
                & \mycell{20\%\\(mean)} & \mycell{20\%\\(var)}
                & \mycell{50\%\\(mean)} & \mycell{50\%\\(var)} \\
    \midrule
    asdf        & 0.1234 & 0.1234 & 0.1234 & 0.1234 & 0.1234 & 0.1234 & 0.1234 & 0.1234 \\
    asdf        & 0.1234 & 0.1234 & 0.1234 & 0.1234 & 0.1234 & 0.1234 & 0.1234 & 0.1234 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabu}
\end{table}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

not to look so bad as

[image]

and instead actually fit:

- Get the first column to fit to the `\diagbox`
- Have the tabu actually fit to `\textwidth`

In fact, if I don't use the `\diagbox`, the tabu is still too wide:

[image]

I am not sure if the first X is actually what I should be using in the first place.

I only get tabu to be `\textwidth` wide if the code is `\begin{tabu} to 0.7\textwidth` - which makes little sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit (2):**

Instead of `tabu to` rather use `tabu spread`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{array, makecell, tabu}
\usepackage{diagbox}

\newcolumntype{Z}{S[
    table-format=1.3,
    round-mode=places,
    round-precision=3]}
\newcommand\mycell[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\makecell{#1}}}% now text in \mycell (column headers) is bold

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \small  % <-- smaller font size
\setlength\tabcolsep{1.5pt}% <-- smaller distances between columns
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}% more open table (bigger vertical space between rows)
\begin{tabu} spread 6pt {X *{8}{Z}}
    \firsthline
\rowfont[c]\bfseries
    \diagbox[width=2.4cm]{method}{missing}
        & \mycell{ 5\%\\(mean)} & \mycell{ 5\%\\(variance)}
        & \mycell{10\%\\(mean)} & \mycell{10\%\\(variance)}
        & \mycell{20\%\\(mean)} & \mycell{20\%\\(variance)}
        & \mycell{50\%\\(mean)} & \mycell{50\%\\(variance)} \\
    \hline
KNN     & 0.1234 & 0.1234 & 0.1234 & 0.1234 & 0.1234 & 0.1234 & 0.1234 & 0.1234 \\
MICE    & 0.1234 & 0.1234 & 0.1234 & 0.1234 & 0.1234 & 0.1234 & 0.1234 & 0.1234 \\
    \lasthline
    \end{tabu}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

With `spread` the table have natural width, so to make its width equal to `\textwidth` a manual tweaking is needed. In above MWE `\tabcolsep` is reduced by "trial and error`method, the same I did with font size and width of`\diagbox`.

**Note:**
As I pointed in the first version of answer, `tabu` is buggy`(this probably source of your trouble) and no more maintained. Instead it I will rather use`tabularx`.

I delete the first version of answer, apparently it not interested anyone :)

Comment: Ah sorry, I just updated my question...

Comment: Can you tell me how to do it now with my update? If I remove booktabs and it's rules, it does not change anything. I made the table contents shorter (as seen in the question by now). What do you mean by "lengths for `diagbox` and `ptext` are not in accordance"? As far as I know, I am not using  the package `ptext`.

Comment: don't use `tabu`. see recent version of my answer.

Comment: @Make42, please se recent edit of my answer. maybe now is more close to what you like to get.